# turtle.done() not working in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, turtle-graphics

This simple Python script:

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.forward(50)
turtle.done()
```

yields an error when running it using Spyder. The first run works as expected, but after that, the IPython console raises a "Terminator". The same happens when using `turtle.exitonclick()` instead of `turtle.done()`. What am I doing wrong?

Note that running it from the CLI works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Spyder but have exchanged comments with others who have similar problems running turtle in similar environments.

If you close the turtle graphics window, it's dead and won't reopen for you. Short of restarting Spyder, you can try adding a `turtle.bye()` (which cleans up some things) after `turtle.done()` (which returns after the main loop exits).  Then try running your program multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble running a turtle graphics program more than once in Spyder, and I solved it by going to "Tools / Preferences". In the "Run" section, under "Console", select "Execute in a new dedicated Python console".

Answer (score 1):

This is because the turtle module (most reference implementations as of today) uses a class variable called `_RUNNING`. Class variables remain false between executions when running in environments like Spyder instead of running as a self-contained Python script. There are two work around for this:

1)

```
import importlib
import turtle
importlib.reload(turtle)
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.forward(50)
turtle.done()
```

2. 

```
import turtle
turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING=True
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.forward(50)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Thanks a lot for the pointer! Do you know what Python version introduced that variable?

Comment: Hi Carlos. Python2.6 extended implementation from 2.5 introduced that variable.

Comment: I have made a commit and PR for this to be updated in the library itself without affecting any other functionality. If that goes through the cpython reviewers/maintainers then I will try to suggest the change to other repos as well.